# Problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, apk

I'm trying to build an apk running **flutter build apk --split-per-abi** and I'm getting this message:

Note that a week ago this wasn't happening.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\sandbox\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 646

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > The value for this property cannot be changed any further.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       5,5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I then ran **flutter doctor -v** to see if android and flutter were outdated.

After updating and restarting Android Studio I'm getting the same error. Any idea what could be the problem?

```
C:\sandbox\AndroidStudioProjects\dataps05>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.18363.1256], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\sandbox\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (7 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)                                                                          
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Post the errors output instead of screenshots

Comment: Edited now, sorry

Comment: What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`? Did you try to build an apk file from the android studio?

Comment: Added the output of flutter doctor, and yes I'm trying to build an apk from Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Do the [following](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11940#issuecomment-732328416) for flutter doctor warnings

```
flutter channel dev
flutter doctor
flutter channel master
flutter doctor
```

and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64625695/13444299) for your problem.

Comment: Couln't make it work. the workaround I used was to downgrade a couple dependencies my project is using and now its working or at least i'm able to run ```flutter build apk```

Comment: Glad you made it, you can try the other solutions in the first link there are many, but it doesn't matter anyway as long you can run your project actually I was in the same situation as you for a long time and it's not affecting anything as long as you installed it the right way.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm stuck on a different problem, I'll edit this comment once I publish that question