# Could not find method android() for arguments [build_cvvl3t62v3wt8en8p0wbmp06l$_run_closure1@12c1bc3e] on root project 'android

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've been trying to run a project to Android Studio and this is where I am stuck, there is a similar question on Stack Overflow but it did not provide a solution to my particular error.

This is the my error!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\chaitanya\Desktop\New Project\verification\android\build.gradle' line: 13
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_cvvl3t62v3wt8en8p0wbmp06l$_run_closure1@12c1bc3e] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please share the output of flutter doctor.

Comment: Did you tried this answer? :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64625695/19807154

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.